# Springboot combined security (Oauth and form) configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I have a web application with two components, dashboard on one side and on the other REST API. I am trying to implement different types of security matching specific URLs (website URL /website/**, rest URL  /API/**** ). I am stuck on configuring the paths to work correspondingly with two types of security. 
Form-based security seems to be working properly but not the OAuth one.

For rest URL I get access denied for everything, even the things that should be public. I first implemented OAuth without form security and that worked perfectly. After adding form-based security in another configuration then 
I get access denied on rest. Authorization server still works fine, 
I get tokens issued properly

Any help would be much appreciated, here is my code below.

FORM SECURITY

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class WebsiteSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .antMatcher("/website/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/website/login","/website/public").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/website/admin/home").hasAuthority("ADMINISTRATOR")
        //.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/website/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/website/authenticate")
        .failureUrl("/website/login?error=true")
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/website/admin/home")
        .and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/website/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/website/login").and().exceptionHandling()

        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .invalidSessionUrl("/website/login?expired=true")
;
    }
}
```

REST SECURITY

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(2)
public class OauthSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
         .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        HTTP
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/docs").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/secured").hasAuthority("ADMINISTRATOR").anyRequest().authenticated();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

RESOURCE SERVER

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .anonymous().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/docs").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/secured").authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

If you need any more information feel free to ask :D Cheers!
EDIT 1 (REQUESTED SPRING SECURITY DEBUG LOGS)

Log for /api/secured with a good token

```
2018-08-11 17:13:30.995 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2018-08-11 17:13:30.995 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/secured'; against '/oauth/token'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.995 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/secured'; against '/oauth/token_key'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/secured'; against '/oauth/check_token'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/secured'; against '/website/**'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/secured'; against '/logout'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /api/secured' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /api/secured' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /api/secured' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.996 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.998 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.998 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.998 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/secured'; against '/api/docs'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.998 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/secured'; against '/api/secured'
2018-08-11 17:13:30.998 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/secured?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe; Attributes: [hasAuthority('ADMINISTRATOR')]
2018-08-11 17:13:30.999 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at 

org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]

    2018-08-11 17:13:30.999 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
    2018-08-11 17:13:30.999 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
    2018-08-11 17:13:30.999 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@30e292
    2018-08-11 17:13:30.999 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token_key'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/check_token'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/website/**'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.000 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error?access_token=ee7e8e8f-8423-481c-9773-cd97099c5dfe reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.002 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
    2018-08-11 17:13:31.002 DEBUG 16256 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: `EnableResourceServer` has `Order(3)` by defautt, hence your `OauthSecurity` is used and this one isn't a resource server configuration. But URL `/api/docs` should work without authentication. Could you add Spring Security logs with level `DEBUG`.

Comment: Dur, This is the debug log, check it out

Comment: As I already wrote, your second configuration is used instead of your resource server configuration. Remove `OauthSecurity` class or change the order to a number greater than 3.

Comment: By setting order 6 for example, oauth works fine but form login security does not

Comment: Form login for URL `/website/**`?

Comment: Yes, managed to solve it just now tho. I set @Order for website security to 4 before, forgot about it. Everything works! Thanks a lot !!!!!